# How can I re-use existing array value in custom config file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have the following array in "config/custom.php"

```
return array(
    'svn_host' => "https://MYSERVERNAME",
    'svn_user' => "deployment",
);
```

Now let's say I add another value, but I want to reuse an existing value from the same array.

```
return array(
    'svn_host' => "https://MYSERVERNAME",
    'svn_user' => "deployment",
    'cmd' => "svn ls --username [I want to use 'svn_user' here]"
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give it a variable above...its a hack, but it'll work

```
$user = "deployement";
return array(
'svn_host' => "https://MYSERVERNAME",
'svn_user' => $user,
'cmd' => "svn ls --username ".$user
);
```

Comment: Sigh sometimes the answer is the simplest answer. Why the heck didnt i think of that.

Comment: If you accept this as an answer...I think I'll feel dirty..hahaha  But I wouldnt mind the rep points....so its a toss up...lol

Comment: not a problem, i was stumped for a bit and moved on. Thanks for the "tip."